# Changing x range

Tags: plotting

I have to plot a function (included below) between x - limits 10^4 to 10^8 and y-limits from 0 to 1. I have the following code:

```
f[x_] := 1 - (Sin[Pi/4])^2 (Sin[1.27*5*10^6/x])^2
Plot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^8}, PlotRange -> {{10^4, 10^8}, {0, 1}}]
```

But the x range is still turning out to be 0 to 10^8. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: You might want to look at `LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^8}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^4, 10^8}, {0, 1}},
 MaxRecursion -> 15]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @BobHanlon -- The problem is that $10^4$ is small enough in comparison to $10^8$ to make it essentially negligible. So when Mathematica labels the ticks on the $x$-axis, consistency requires that it labels the lowest tick as $0$ (so that it's counting up in multiples of $10^7$) rather than $10^4$. But notice that the vertical axis doesn't appear. That's because it's being drawn at $x = 0$, which is (*just*) outside the plot range. Changing the `AxesOrigin` to be within the `PlotRange`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^8}, PlotRange -> {{10^4, 10^8}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {10^4, 0}]
```

and the vertical axis appears

[image]

So `PlotRange` was actually doing what you told it, it was just hard to tell because of how the ticks on the $x$-axis were labelled.

As @BobHanlon pointed out, `LogLinearPlot` would fix that.

```
LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^8}, PlotRange -> {{10^4, 10^8}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]